# Recursion function on a struct in Golang

Tags: recursion, go

I have the following code to organise `*Widget` structs into a hierarchy. `Parent()` returns the widget with an ID of the caller's parentID. The hierarchy can be up to 4 or 5 levels deep.

```
type Widget struct {
  ID int64
  ParentID int64
}

func (w *Widget) Parent() *Widget {
  // Returns the widget with an ID of w.ParentID
}
```

What I want to achieve is a function which aggregates the parent, as well as the parent's parent etc. to the top of the hierarchy, and returns a slice of all of the parent IDs. As I don't know the depth of the hierarchy, I think I need some sort of programmatic recursion to get the parent of each parent, which would do something like the following:

```
func (w *Widget) AllParents() []*Widget {
  var parentWidgets []*Widget
  x := w.Parent()
  parentWidgets = append(parentWidgets, x)
  y := x.Parent()
  parentWidgets = append(parentWidgets, y)
  ...
  return parentWidgets
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to step higher and higher in the hierarchy until you reach the root. Assuming `Widget.Parent()` returns `nil` if the `Widget` is the "root" (meaning it has no parent):

#### Iterative solution

Here is the solution with a simple `for` loop:

```
func (w *Widget) AllParents() []*Widget {
    var ws []*Widget
    for parent := w.Parent(); parent != nil; parent = parent.Parent() {
        ws = append(ws, parent)
    }
    return ws
}
```

This method will return `nil` if called on the "root" ([zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for all slice types). In other cases, it will return the "path" *from the direct parent leading to the "root"*.

Here's a little test program. It creates a root widget with `ID = 0`, a child with `ID = 1` and a "grandchild" with `ID = 2`, and prints `AllParents()` called on each. To implement `Widget.Parent()`, I used a simple "widget registry" map.

Result as expected:

```
Parents of 0:
Parents of 1: 0
Parents of 2: 1 0
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xsFsL3wpDz).

```
var wreg = map[int64]*Widget{}

func (w *Widget) Parent() *Widget {
    // Returns the widget with an ID of w.ParentID
    return wreg[w.ParentID]
}

func main() {
    w := &Widget{0, -1}
    wreg[w.ID] = w
    w2 := &Widget{1, 0}
    wreg[w2.ID] = w2
    w3 := &Widget{2, 1}
    wreg[w3.ID] = w3

    printParents(w)
    printParents(w2)
    printParents(w3)
}

func printParents(w *Widget) {
    fmt.Printf("Parents of %d:", w.ID)
    for _, w := range w.AllParents() {
        fmt.Print(" ", w.ID)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

#### Recursive solution

Of course it can be solved using recursion too:

```
func (w *Widget) AllParents() []*Widget {
    if parent := w.Parent(); parent == nil {
        return nil
    } else {
        return append(parent.AllParents(), parent)
    }
}
```

This solution returns the "path" *from the root leading to the direct parent*.

Running the above test program with this implementation, output is:

```
Parents of 0:
Parents of 1: 0
Parents of 2: 0 1
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1HvPP-ZTLd).